# How do I update a label after clicking a Button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.minsize(250, 250)
win.title("Point Clicker")
win.resizable(0, 0)

# Make Save fuction
SaveButton = Button(win, text="Save Progress", command=None)
SaveButton.place(x=75, y=215)

value = 1
IncreaserPrice = 50
point = 0
print("You have " + str(point) + " points")

def AddPoint():
    global point
    point = point + value
    print("You have " + str(point) + " points")

def BuyDoubler():

    global value, point, IncreaserPrice

    if point > IncreaserPrice or point == IncreaserPrice:
        print("You have bought the Point Doubler")
        value = value + 1
        point = point - IncreaserPrice
        IncreaserPrice += 50
        Price1 = Label(win, text="Price = " + str(IncreaserPrice) + " points")
        print("You have " + str(point) + " points left")


    else:
        print("You dont have enough points for this")


Clicker = Button(win, text="Click for points", command=AddPoint)
Clicker.pack()

ClickIncreaser = Button(win, text="Buy Point Doubler", command=BuyDoubler)
ClickIncreaser.pack()

Price1 = Label(win, text="Price = " + str(DoublerPrice) + " points")
Price1.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

I am trying to make a Knock-Off Cookie Clicker using python Tkinter and I am trying to update the price label after the user has bought an increaser.
How do I update the label after a button has been clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a tkinter label after already `pack`ing it or `grid`ing it using the method `Label.config`. Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

screen = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(text="Label")
label.pack()
label.config(text="Label updated")
screen.mainloop()
```

the label that had been `pack`ed says Label Updated instead of Label.

Comment: @Debil.exe Great hope you can move forward with your fun little project.

Comment: Thanks! 
I am also going to make a lot of games in the future!
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

All of those parameters are available as properties of the object.  You need to alter the object you have, not create a new object.

```
   Price1.text = "Price = %d points" % IncreaserPrice
```

Do you understand you can use `>=` in the `if` statement instead of two separate comparisons?

Comment: oh yeah i accidently used two operators instead of one.